# Play Framework Async Controller

Tags: asynchronous, playframework-2.3

I'm having problems with play async request handling. For testing purposes, I've written the below controller method. When I make 4 subsequent requests to asyncSleep, my play instance gets blocked until one of the asyncSleep requests returns.

```
public static Promise<Result> asyncSleep() {
   Promise<Integer> promiseOfInt = Promise.promise(new Function0<Integer>() {
      public Integer apply() {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(60000L);
         } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return 9;
       }
    });
    return promiseOfInt.map(new Function<Integer, Result>() {
        public Result apply(Integer i) {
            return ok("asyncSleep ok " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this in dev mode? Because Play processes requests in dev mode serially.

Comment: sleep means you are still blocking, using the cpu. I think it could also be related to how promises and Futures are implemented in scala. The doc says "In the event that some of the callbacks never complete (e.g. the callback contains an infinite loop), the other callbacks may not be executed at all. In these cases, a potentially blocking callback must use the blocking construct (see below)" read more @ http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: Which executioncontext do you provide?